# creating temp table from a data frame in R using RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a data frame which I need to write as a **temp table** in R using RPostgreSQL package.

Example:

```
>data(USArrests)
#Assuming that we have already established a connection to the postgres db
#Let conn be the postgres connection object
>dbWriteTable(conn, "temp_table_data", USArrests, temp.table=TRUE)
```

This does not work. The argument temp.table is seemingly ignored.

If there is no way out to deal with dbWriteTable, is there anyway to write a data frame as a temp table ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that temp.table=TRUE might even work?

Comment: Probably from this [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/issues/detail?id=32). It notes, however, that with that driver, you shouldn't try and do this.

Comment: If your underlying purpose here is just to apply a PostgreSQL sql statement to an R data frame then you could try sqldf.  For example this counts the rows in `USArrests`: `library(RPostgreSQL); library(sqldf); sqldf('select count(*) from "USArrests"')` . See http://sqldf.googlecode.com and `?sqldf` .

Comment: @Grothendieck: Thanks for the pointer. Much appreciated. The road block which I'm facing currently is that sqldf is not available for R version 2.13.0. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 7):

you can use the argument 
`is.temp = TRUE` and it works

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of would be to return the data frame as a result set, and write it to a temporary table using a wrapping function written in plpgsql.  This means that you would have to break up the logic into a calculation and a storage layer.